# Finding independent functions in $(X^n,\mathcal A^{\otimes n},\mu^{\times n})$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

So basically I am having a hard time trying to understand an example given in **Measures, Integrals and Martingales** (Schilling, R.)

The idea is to replace the probability space $(X,\mathcal A,\mu)$ by the $n$-fold product measure space $(X^n,\mathcal A^{\otimes n},\mu^{\times n})$ (which is in turn a probability space).

Then, we have a family of function $(u_j)_{j\in \mathbb N}\subset\mathcal L^1(\mathcal A)$ and we define 
$$\tilde u_j(x_1,\dots,x_n):=u_j(x_j),  j=1,2,\dots,n$$

Now, the author says that the independence of the $\tilde u_j$'s is straightforward but I am not sure if I have this right.

> The definition of independence given by the author is the following: 
>   A family of integrable functions $(f_j)_{j\in \mathbb N}$ is called
>   independent if:
>   $$\mu\bigg(\bigcap_{j=1}^Mu_j^{-1}(B_j)\bigg)=\prod_{j=1}^M\mu(u_j^{-1}(B_j))$$
>   holds for all $M\in\mathbb N$ and any choice of Borel measurable sets
>   $B_1,B_2,\dots,B_M$.

---

**What I've tried so far:**

$$\mu^{\times n} \bigg(\bigcap_{j=1}^M\tilde u_j^{-1}(B_j)\bigg)=\int_{X^n}1_{\bigcap_{j=1}^M\tilde u_j^{-1}(B_j)}d(\mu^{\times n})$$
since $\bigg(X^n\cap\bigcap_{j=1}^M\tilde u_j^{-1}(B_j)\bigg)\subset X^n$ and we are dealing with probability spaces we know that this integral is finite and by means of Fubini's theorem we can write:

$$=\int\dots\int 1_{\bigcap_{j=1}^M \tilde u_j^{-1}(B_j)}(x_1,\dots,x_n)\mu(dx_1)\dots\mu(dx_n) $$

Now I guess I can write the **indicator function of the intersection** as the product of indicator functions, right?

$$\int\dots\int \prod_{j=1}^M 1_{\tilde u_j^{-1}(B_j)}(x_1,\dots,x_n)\mu(dx_1)\dots\mu(dx_n)$$

then

$$\int\dots\int \prod_{j=1}^M 1_{B_j}\big(\tilde u_j(x_1,\dots,x_n)\big)\mu(dx_1)\dots\mu(dx_n)$$

and we are done since this equals

$$=\int\dots\int \prod_{j=1}^M 1_{B_j}\big(u_j(x_j)\big)\mu(dx_1)\dots\mu(dx_n)$$
$$=\int\dots\int \prod_{j=1}^M 1_{u_j^{-1} (B_j)}\big(x_j\big)\mu(dx_1)\dots\mu(dx_n)$$
$$=\prod_{j=1}^M\mu(u_j^{-1}(B_j))$$

Anyway  I am worried about the fact that what I've shown (maybe incorrectly) is that:

$$\color{red}{\mu^{\times n}}\bigg(\bigcap_{j=1}^M\tilde u_j^{-1}(B_j)\bigg)=\prod_{j=1}^M\color{green}{\mu}(u_j^{-1}(B_j))$$

Is this a problem?
Did I commit some mistake?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not a problem. You're showing independence under the measure $\mu^{\times n}$. The $\tilde{u}_j$ are not random variables on $X$.

Comment: I see so I can write ${\mu^{\times n}}\bigg(\bigcap_{j=1}^M\tilde u_j^{-1}(B_j)\bigg)=\prod_{j=1}^M{\mu}(u_j^{-1}(B_j))=\prod_{j=1}^M {\mu^{\times n}}(\tilde u_j^{-1}(B_j))$, right?

Comment: Yes, by definition of the product measure and the fact that $\tilde{u}_j^{-1}(B_j)=\{x_j\in u_j^{-1}(B_j)\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mu_n\equiv\mu^{\times n}$ and $A_j:=u_j^{-1}(B_j)$. Then

\begin{align}
\mu_n\!\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^M \tilde{u}_j^{-1}(B_j) \right)&=\mu_n(A_1\times A_2\times\cdots\times A_M) \\
&=\prod_{j=1}^M\mu(A_j)=\prod_{j=1}^M\mu_n\!\left(\tilde{u}_j^{-1}(B_j)\right),
\end{align}
where the second equality follows form the definition of product measures.